# Speeding up a custom aggregate for window function

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am looking for alternatives to this code which would run faster

```
inp = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["1", "A",  7, 2],
    ["1", "A", 14, 3],
    ["1", "A", 35, 2],
    ["1", "A", 42, 3],
    ["1", "B", 14, 1],
    ["1", "B", 84, 2],
    ["2", "A", 14, 1],
    ["2", "A", 21, 1],
    ["2", "A", 21, 2],
  ], schema=["id","grp","elap","lbl"])
inp.show()
```

Desired output:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from collections import Counter

thresh = 2
days = 49

#smoothing by looking back for n weeks, and based on minimum frequency
@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def best_label(lst):
  ctr = Counter(lst)
  for N in range(thresh,1,-1):
    tmp = [k for k,v in ctr.items() if v>=N]
    if len(tmp)>0: return max(tmp)

w = W.partitionBy("id", "grp").orderBy("elap").rangeBetween(-days, 0)
out = inp.withColumnRenamed("lbl", "lbl_orig")\
  .withColumn("lst", F.collect_list("lbl_orig").over(w))\
  .withColumn("lbl_smooth", best_label(F.col("lst")))\
  .withColumn("lbl", F.coalesce("lbl_smooth", "lbl_orig"))\
  .drop("lbl_orig", "lst", "lbl_smooth")
out.orderBy("id", "grp", "elap").show()
# +---+---+----+---+
# | id|grp|elap|lbl|
# +---+---+----+---+
# |  1|  A|   7|  2|
# |  1|  A|  14|  3|
# |  1|  A|  35|  2|
# |  1|  A|  42|  3|
# |  1|  B|  14|  1|
# |  1|  B|  84|  2|
# |  2|  A|  14|  1|
# |  2|  A|  21|  1|
# |  2|  A|  21|  1|
# +---+---+----+---+
```

I am running this on a dataframe with 300 million rows and it takes about 8mins.

Comment: can you please describe the intended operation(s)?

Comment: if the thresh is increased to 3, and there are some values that occur thrice, `best_label` will return the most recent of the 2 values - (one for `N=3` and one for `N=2`)

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation is slow because of the `udf`. Try creating Spark native algorithms when possible.

You can use the following. (Originally I thought it would be possible using 2 windows, but I was not able to come up with a solution.)

This uses higher-order Spark functions. The idea is that you collect data to list, similarly like you did, but together with the element you can calculate the count and use it later.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
inp = spark.createDataFrame(
    [["1", "A",  7, 2],
     ["1", "A", 14, 3],
     ["1", "A", 35, 2],
     ["1", "A", 42, 3],
     ["1", "A", 43, 3],
     ["1", "A", 44, 3],
     ["1", "A", 45, 2],
     ["1", "A", 46, 2],
     ["1", "A", 47, 2],
     ["1", "A", 48, 4],
     ["1", "A", 49, 4],
     ["1", "B", 14, 1],
     ["1", "B", 84, 2],
     ["2", "A", 14, 1],
     ["2", "A", 21, 1],
     ["2", "A", 21, 2],
    ], ["id","grp","elap","lbl"])

thresh = 2
days = 49
```

Script:

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id", "grp").orderBy("elap").rangeBetween(-days, 0)
df = inp.withColumn(
    "lists",
    F.transform(
        F.collect_set("lbl").over(w),
        lambda x: F.array(
            x,
            F.size(F.filter(F.collect_list("lbl").over(w), lambda y: y == x))
        )
    )
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "lbl",
    F.coalesce(F.sort_array(F.filter("lists", lambda x: x[1] >= thresh), False)[0][0], "lbl")
).drop("lists")

df.show()
# +---+---+----+---+
# | id|grp|elap|lbl|
# +---+---+----+---+
# |  1|  A|   7|  2|
# |  1|  A|  14|  3|
# |  1|  A|  35|  2|
# |  1|  A|  42|  3|
# |  1|  A|  43|  3|
# |  1|  A|  44|  3|
# |  1|  A|  45|  3|
# |  1|  A|  46|  3|
# |  1|  A|  47|  3|
# |  1|  A|  48|  3|
# |  1|  A|  49|  4|
# |  1|  B|  14|  1|
# |  1|  B|  84|  2|
# |  2|  A|  14|  1|
# |  2|  A|  21|  1|
# |  2|  A|  21|  1|
# +---+---+----+---+
```